# Aurelia UI Virtualization keeps scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I'm facing two problems with my Aurelia UI Virtualization list. I'm using the latest github version of the plugin and it's (sort of) working.

First I had the problem that "element.getBoundingClientRect" was not a function. After debugging it seems that the "element" was not a div but a comment. That was because of the auto-generated comments from Aurelia (, ). After also debugging the live demo of the plugin, it seems that something in the package was changed between the latest version and the demo version. I've changed it like the demo and that part was resolved. I've changed this in the virtual-repeat.js:

From:

```
let firstViewElement = this.view(0).lastChild;
```

To:

```
let firstViewElement = this.view(0).firstChild.nextElementSibling;
```

That solved the problem with my function issue and the list is shown as expected. From my 400 items, it only shows a part (11 items) of it in the HTML Source.

Sadly it won't scroll like the expected behavior. When I scroll down and up the list, the first few pixels everything is working fine. But when the plugin needs to load new items on the bottom/top, the page keeps auto-scrolling till almost the end. Then it stops and you can scroll the last part manually. When I inspect the page, it looks like the elements are correctly replaced for new ones, so that's not the problem.

I've tried to find the part where the scroll goes wrong, and when I skip the "adjustBufferHeights()" part, the page is not scrolling on it's own anymore. The only thing is that the list scrolls out of view (because of the buffers not adjusting anymore). The page looks something like:

```
<div><!-- parent element -->
  <div> <!--upperbuffer--></div>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article> 
    <article></article>
    ... <!-- about 11 elements are loaded -->
  <div> <!--bottombuffer--></div>
</div>
```

Without the adjustBufferHeights(), the elements are still refreshing and looks like that part is still working. The only thing is that the page comes beneath the 11 loaded elements, and without the upperbuffers height increasing, the elements comes outside view. Someone a clue what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a gist or gist.run of your problem? The first error you mentioned typically happens when you have the repeater on an unexpected element, or the element it's on doesn't actually exist in the DOM yet (typically edge cases).
There are a few issues out there for adding and removing elements to various places in the array, and if you have ideas on how to fix it, PR's are more than welcome!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the tricky part of providing a gist is that we've build it in our system. I will try to provide a demo today with the components we're using. It looks like the adjustBufferHeights() function triggers the onScroll function and it stays in a loop.

Comment: Update: It looks like the page is not really "scrolling". It's because of the changing buffers at the bottom and top. When scrolling down, after around 3 elements, the list starts adjust the buffer heights. The buffer at the bottom decreases and the buffer at top increased. That's why it looked like the page is scrolling, but actually the list is "moving".

Comment: It sounds like something is triggering those buffer events to change. Do you have any kind of special behavior surrounding your list?

Comment: Yeah, the plugin triggers the buffer heights with the "adjustBufferHeights()" function (build in Aurelia-ui-virtualization). But the question is, what is triggering the "onscroll" and let it keep scrolling through the items. 

Yesterday I wasn't able to provide an example. I will try it today. Thanks for the support.

Comment: How can I add the aurelia-ui-virtualization package to the gist? I've a running aurelia gist now, but want to implement the package.

Comment: You'd have to pull from some CDN probably to get the library in. You could try Code Sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/2w8J7n9W), might be a bit easier. If all else fails, if you just make a github repo that we can pull and test, that would be helpful (sorry for the delay too, was out on vacation).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, when setting up the codesandbox, I've figured out what causes the issue. The plugin can't handle the "with.bind" attribute. So what causes the "element.getBoundingClientRect" and the crash in first place. So when I "hacked"that part, I was looking for the (wrong) scroll issue. That was caused by the hack I think. The problem is that the plugin can't handle with.bind. I've setup the codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/4xwP3NEQn

Comment: Are you trying to use the `with` binding so you don't have to use `person.name`?

Comment: Yes that's right. Is it the wrong way?

Comment: I don't think it should be a wrong way... Probably just a case not accounted for yet apparently. Typically, I don't use the with binding in this case because it keeps code a bit more explicit, but that's purely a style choice. Ultimately, it sounds like it's probably a bug (especially if it works without the `with` binding). If you could write up an issue over in the repo (assuming there's not one already), that'd be fantastic!

Comment: I've added an issue in the aurelia-ui-virtualization github: https://github.com/aurelia/ui-virtualization/issues/110. Thanks a lot for the support!